# Can we detect gravitons this way?

Tags: gravity, experimental-physics, gravitational-waves

First, we shoot a collection of particles (let's exclude gravitons from these, just for the sake of clarity) through a large region of spacetime in which the stress-energy tensor is zero and make them impact on a screen somewhere far away. A pattern will emerge.
Then we do the same with a second collection of particles (as much as possible identical to the first collection) but this time a gravitational wave is present.

We can vary a number of things. We can choose different particles (from photons to atoms). We can let the momenta of the particles have different angles (though they all are moving parallel wrt each other) wrt the direction in which the gravitational wave propagates. The same can be done but wrt to the screen. You can also vary the distance between the screen and the wave. The same can be done for the source of particles. For sure there will be different patterns visible in both cases. For example when the screen is placed far enough. Or not? Is it possible to detect gravitons with this construction (or, equivalently, to rule them out)?

Comment: This setup isn't very clear to me. Are you asking if you can do the double slit experiment with gravitons? If so the answer is in principle yes if you can produce a collimated beam of gravitons, develop a material that absorbs them with high probability so that it makes sense to talk about slits, and reliably detect them on a screen. In practice you will have major problems with all three of those steps. There's an interesting paper by Freeman Dyson about how it may be impossible in principle to detect gravitons:  https://inspirehep.net/literature/1257811

Comment: @Andrew You have: a collection of particles, confined to a volume. You try to make the collections look as much as possible the same. The collections are sent through space to a screen. One collection after the other. Without a gravitational wave, you'd expect a different pattern to be seen on the screen than with a wave.

Comment: How are you going to find a region of spacetime with zero energy momentum tensor? Just shooting the particles themselves guarantees that isn't true, not to mention things like the CMB/CNB that are ever present.

Comment: @Triatticus Well, let's assume two spacetimes as empty as possible. They only differ by the presence of a gravitational wave.Of course the spacetime is not empty anymore when we shoot the particle field through it. The fields are tried to make as identical as possible.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder I'm still confused, are you trying to detect gravitons or gravitational waves (classical coherent states of gravitons?). When you "shoot a particle", what particle are you shooting?

Comment: @Andrew All right. A gravitational wave distorts spacetime. So if a bunch of particles travels through this wave the wave will affect the particles in a different way than when the bunch travels through empty space (without the wave). This influence must translate in a different pattern to see on the screen. So you detect the wave in an indirect way, by means of its influence on the bunch of particles. The particles can be varied. I asked this in the question. Maybe some particles work better than others.

Comment: @Andrew The particles used can be any particles (maybe some fit best). electrons positrons, photons (which might be the best). On top of gravitational waves themselves is it possible to detect graininess in the wave (which would hint at quantization)?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder As others have said in the answers, measuring the phase difference between two paths induced by a gravitational wave is the strategy of LIGO. Photons are used because they are bosons, so you can amplify the signal by putting many photons into the same state, each of which is affected the same way by a gravitational wave. Measuring the quantum nature of the gravitational wave (ie measuring gravitons) in this way is hopeless though. Take a look at the article by Dyson.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the particles, it is that one cannot control and focus a gravitational wave. The gravitational waves detected by LIGO, the first evidence of gravitational waves, [were coming from the merging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO#Detections) of two black holes  .

There is no way to detect or predict such occurrences, and the LIGO "screen" is continents long.

Gravitons are another layer of complexity , at the moment experiments are trying tof find their existence through [polarization of the cosmic microwave background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BICEP_and_Keck_Array#BICEP2) radiation. Having a beam of individual gravitons interact with individual particles is science fiction.

Comment: What about projecting a photon field onto a screen? Isn't it possible to detect small spacetime fluctuations between the source and the screen? If the photon field stays constant (?) you would think that the observed pattern on the screen is changed when a gravitational field passes.

Comment: read the Ligo experiment, that is what happens, two perpendicular laser paths are interfered differently because of the spacecurvature changes from the gravitational field. Gravitons are another story.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing LIGO: a beam of photons is sent through an empty region and allowed to interfere with a reference beam. When gravitational waves arrive they cause a shift of the interference fringes.

You may want the wave to be fully inside the test chamber rather than affecting it as a whole, but note that the effect of the wave - periodic changes in the distance to the target - happens in either case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can produce gravitational waves at will. At least, strong enough to be measurable. Also, the setup used to measure gravitational waves is *extremely* sensitive and precise, because they are very weak. Noticing if a gravitational wave has any impact on a beam of particles is basically impossible at the moment, considering on top of everything else that those same particles will interact with each other with other forces.